# Javascript - HTML Video readyState DOM undefined

Tags: javascript, html5-video

This is the code:

```
var meme = "";
meme +=     '<div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this);" style="max-width: calc(100% - 2px);">';
meme +=         '<video loop class="video" style="max-width: 100%;">';
meme +=             '<source src="" type="video/mp4" id="video-preview" />';
meme +=         '</video>'; 

meme +=         '<div class="gif_button" style="display: flex;">GIF</div>';             
meme +=     '</div>';       

$('#previewholder_area').empty();
$('#previewholder_area').html(meme);
$('#video-preview').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(bla.files[0]));

var videoElement = document.getElementById("video-preview");

console.log('wth');
console.log(videoElement.readyState);

videoElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', (e) => {
    console.log('hello?');

    if(videoElement.readyState >= 3){
        readURL(bla);
    }
});

videoElement.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
   //Video should now be loaded but we can add a second check
    makeToast("Invalid Video Format!", "error", 4000);      
    reset_upload();
});
```

Console only prints out:

```
wth
undefined
```

Whats going on here? It worked yesterday and the video still loads without a problem. I didn't make any changes since yesterday.

```
addEventListener
```

isn't doing anything, neither `loadeddata` nor `error`

Comment: does the element with the id "video-preview" exist on the page when the code is called?

Comment: No it's generated as you can see in the code on line 4 and the video loads without a problem in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around this is how it works again now:

```
var meme = "";
meme +=     '<div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this);" style="max-width: calc(100% - 2px);">';
meme +=         '<video loop class="video videopreview">';
meme +=             '<source src="" type="video/mp4" />';
meme +=         '</video>'; 

meme +=         '<div class="gif_button" style="display: flex;">GIF</div>';             
meme +=     '</div>';       

$('#previewholder_area').empty();
$('#previewholder_area').html(meme);
$('.videopreview source').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(bla.files[0]));

const videoElement = $(".videopreview");


videoElement.get(0).addEventListener('loadeddata', (e) => {
    if(videoElement.get(0).readyState >= 3){
        readURL(bla);
    }
});

videoElement.get(0).addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    makeToast("Invalid Video Format!", "error", 4000);      
    reset_upload();
});
```

I don't know why it needs to be like that now and why it worked the other way until yesterday